# Encrypted ZIP and plain text attack

Tags: known-plaintext-attack, password-based-encryption

I have a Zip archive containing a single password-protected file `file.txt`. 
The encryption is "ZIP 2.0 Default Encryption" (ZipCrypto).

I know what kind of text (sentences) the "file.txt" contains.

- Is it possible to use known-plaintext in that case? Or,
- Do I need exactly a second known encrypted file to use this type of attack?

Comment: This might help https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/what-is-safer-zipcrypto-or-aes-256

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe since the *answer* to the other question includes the required resources saying that a plaintext attack is indeed possible, even if the question isn't directly about plaintext attack...