# How can a cryptographic algorithm be vulnerable?

Tags: encryption

I was looking for an encryption algorithm to use with my 7zip archives and I read that there is a solution called ZipCrypto that was said to be very vulnerable.

Since I'd suppose these type of vulnerabilities aren't of the kind of those found in an Application Security context (heap-based, stack-based...) and given that I don't know a lot about these kind of algorithms, how can a cryptographic solution be vulnerable and exploited?

Comment: Might be a dupe of [What is safer: ZipCrypto or AES-256?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3791/18298) and [7zip : Why does encrypting the same file with AES-256 not give the same output?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77546/18298)

Comment: See http://infozip.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#crypto and [7zip provides ZipCrypto for backward compability](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/b91e4a57/) nothing more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cryptography we have some standard sets of security notions. For encryption, those are [explained here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/easy-explanation-of-ind-security-notions), for signatures they're [explained here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/what-do-the-signature-security-abbreviations-like-euf-cma-mean/44210).

An algorithm is vulnerable if it doesn't meet the security notions its authors claim it meets. For encryption it's generally best to consider anything that doesn't satisfy the notion IND-CCA3 as "insecure"; while there are some cases where a system can remain secure with the weaker notions that tends to be an exception to the normal rule.

ZipCrypto doesn't even satisfy the weakest of the encryption security notions, IND-CPA. AES (as used in 7-Zip) *is* IND-CPA secure, though it doesn't satisfy the stronger notions. If you can't afford the risks of using a scheme that's only IND-CPA secure, consider [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) for encryption. Otherwise 7-zip's AES-CBC encryption is fine.